# Are there any economic peer-reviewed journals dedicated to, or at least committed to publishing, replication studies?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, replication

Because it is widely perceived that generally science has a reproducibility and replication problems recently some replication journals were set up such as [ReScienceX](http://rescience.org/x) (see [Roesch & Rougier, 2020](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-01328-2)).

Is there any example of such initiative within the field of economics? If not is there any journal that at least committed to publish more or give more space to replication studies? [Mueller-Langer et al (2019)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0048733318301847) show that only 0.1% of studies published in top 50 economic journals between 1974 and 2014 could be classified as replication studies.

Nonetheless, 2014 is almost decade ago, one would hope that some economic journals would take some explicit commitments in this area, are there any examples of that?

When it comes to pure replication journals I am interested in any examples, when it comes to some specific policies or commitments to more replication I am only interested in [Q1 or Q2 journals](https://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php?category=2002).

Comment: Note that a large proportion of economics papers are theoretical in nature. That is they pose some theoretical model on how a particular feature of the economy works and then study that model. Whether this model makes reasonably accurate predictions in the real world is not part of the paper. Knowing this would of course be very useful but studying that would not be a replication because the initial paper didn't do it.

Comment: @quarague that used to be true about 20 years ago but empirical research of economic literature shows that more than 50% of all publications nowadays in almost every field of economics except for pure microeconomics is empirical https://www.aeaweb.org/research/charts/an-empirical-turn-in-economics-research

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A notable journal that has a dedicated replication section is the Journal of Applied Econometrics, which contains a detailed description [on their webpage](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/page/journal/10991255/homepage/news.html#replication55/homepage/news.html#replication).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

[*Journal of the Economic Science Association* (*JESA*)](https://www.springer.com/journal/40881)

> JESA will focus on publishing shorter papers (original articles, methodological pieces, surveys, comments on recently published experimental papers), and article types that are important yet under-represented in the experimental literature (i.e., **replications**, minor extensions, robustness checks, meta-analyses, and good experimental designs even if obtaining null results). JESA will periodically publish special issues with themes of particular interest for economics experiments, including articles solicited from leading scholars both within and outside of experimental economics.

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing no. But more importantly, I think you might want to contact [Jan Höfler](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/7215/jan-h%c3%b6ffler) of the [Replication Wiki](https://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)?

At the bottom of the opening page (of Replication Wiki) we read

> ...in empirical social science research, it is not yet common practice to publish replication findings. This wiki serves as a database of empirical studies, the availability of replication material for them and of replication studies. It can help teaching replication to students. Seminars at several faculties internationally were already taught for which the information of this database was used.
>
> So far the focus has been on some leading journals in economics. Replication results can be published as [replication working papers](https://ideas.repec.org/s/stg/wpaper.html) of the University of Göttingen's [Center for Statistics](http://www.uni-goettingen.de/en/420023.html).

The site seems to somewhat regularly updated. There are also useful external links for replication news, like the one to the [2021 "Open Science and Replicability in the Behavioural Social Sciences" Conference](https://www.tu-chemnitz.de/hsw/mkz/OpenScienceCon.php).

Comment: Thanks that’s a good idea to contact them

Answer (score 2):

The recently launched [Journal of Comments and Replications in Economics (JCRE)](https://www.jcr-econ.org/) specializes in this.

For up-to-date call for papers, see also the dedicated page curated by the  [Institute for replication (I4R)](https://i4replication.org/publishing.html). At the time of writing, the [Journal of Economic Behavior and Organization](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/journal-of-economic-behavior-and-organization/call-for-papers/the-science-and-practice-of-replication-in-experimental-economics) has an open call for replications of experimental results.